# multiple definitions for serial queue online, so got confused

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

i have came across two kind of definitions for serial queue after reading online.

1st version: serial queue performs one task at a time.

2nd version: serial queue execute tasks serially, so task1 have to finish before task2 starts.

can you tell me which one is right exactly ?

Comment: Both version are saying exactly the same thing in different way.

Comment: both version sounds different, 1st version says that one task at a time, mean if i have multiple tasks, then i can do context switching....

Comment: Take a peek here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue/1414982-maxconcurrentoperationcount , statement 2 is about some special cases. i.e setting concurrent operation count set to 1.

Comment: in context switching also you can do max 1 operation at a time.

Comment: Remember that GCD queues and iOS multitasking in general is non-preemptive. A task executing on a serial queue executed until completion. It cannot be interrupted for another task on the same queue to execute

Answer (score 1):

As Ratul Sharker said, both versions are saying the same thing.

**1st version:** serial queue performs one task at a time.

You only can have one task running, so your task have to finish before another is started.

1. Task 1 starts
2. Task 1 ends
3. Task 2 starts
4. Task 2 ends

**2nd version:** serial queue execute tasks serially, so task1 have to finish before task2 starts

Obviously, the result is the same as the 1st version.

**But!** That 2nd version might be speaking of callbacks or another sort of paradigms with multithreading, where you *could* run more than one task, but Task 2 will wait for Task 1 to end.

In any case, two tasks are serial if one starts after the other ends, simple as that.

Comment: no, one task at a time means for example suppose you are working on ios projects. now tell me if 1) doing one project at a time is same as 2) doing project serially ??? not same, right ?

Comment: Yes, it is. One project at a time, I work in one project, end, and then I work in another. Projects serially, I end one and then I do the other. 1st version assumes that the task is finished, not just doing one task midway and then switching to another and then back, thats not how (usually) programming works.

Answer (score 0):

From the [appledoc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue)

> Operations within a queue are organized according to their readiness, priority level, and interoperation dependencies, and are executed accordingly. If all of the queued operations have the same queuePriority and are ready to execute when they are put in the queue—that is, their isReady property returns true—they’re executed in the order in which they were submitted to the queue. Otherwise, the operation queue always executes the one with the highest priority relative to the other ready operations.
>
> However, you should never rely on queue semantics to ensure a specific execution order of operations, because changes in the readiness of an operation can change the resulting execution order. Interoperation dependencies provide an absolute execution order for operations, even if those operations are located in different operation queues. An operation object is not considered ready to execute until all of its dependent operations have finished executing.

So the queued operations are intended to be executed serially, but it never garunteed. To ensure execution order dependencies must be specified to get the full proof exact behaviour.

Comment: FWIW, the above caveat only applies to operation queues, but not to dispatch queues. (All of the OP’s previous questions have been about GCD, and that’s likely the case here, too.)